# Permanently Assign Windows Attributes To Applications

Tags: interface

I use multiple workspaces like most sane people on Ubuntu 20.04.  My  question is:

How do I **permanently** assign window attributes to an application window whenever it launches such as "Always on Available Workspace" and "Always on Top"?

thx

Comment: devilpie or devilspie2 when on Xorg, no way on Wayland.

Comment: How can I tell if I am on Xorg or Wayland?

Comment: I got it... I am on X11 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used   Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Wow.. installed devilspie2.. reading the tutorial.. lot of work for 2 fairly simple and commonly desired window functions... does 22.04 address this problem? Or do I really need to get into scripting just to an app window available in all workspaces?

Comment: Once familiar with devilspie, it is a set up and forget approach. Running it myself for years. No, there is no "support" for this in Gnome Desktop, perhaps there is in KDE.

Comment: Sorry for the whining.. just busy.. scripting it is... :-/